# How to create columns inside Dojo dgrid?

Tags: dojo, dgrid

How do I do to insert new columns in my dgrid?

My code:

```js
window.grid = new DataGrid({bufferRows: Infinity}, "gridResultsDiv");

for (var i = 0; i < layoutFields.length; i++) {
  var newColumn = [{ field: layoutFields[i].field, name: layoutFields[i].name }];

  grid.set("columns", newColumn);
}
```

But the last column of my array `layoutFields` still is present afterwards.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "the last column of my array layoutFields still is present afterwards" ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code and now all columns are shown:

```
            grid = new (declare([DataGrid, Selection]))({
                bufferRows: Infinity,
                columns: layoutFields, // layoutFields is my array with fields and labels.
                selectionMode: "single"
            }, "gridRresultsDiv");

            var memStore = new Memory({ data: data });
            grid.set("store", memStore);
            grid.startup();
```

tks